# what browser plugin that lets you override html of a website automatically

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Can anyone suggest a browser plugin that will let me override a website whenever I am loading a particular website.

**Example Scenario:**

Whenever I load yahoo.com I want to change on how it renders the html and behave.

- It needs to be able to manipulate the DOM. example, it can change the attribute of an `<img height="" width="" />`, example the width and height of the image.
- Aside from changing attributes it also need to be able to inject new elements. example i can insert new `<divs>` or `<p>`.
- I also need to be able to manipulate the head tag as I like to insert external CSS and JS for the overrides.

I primarily use Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome has native support and Firefox via a plugin for user scripts (also called [greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) scripts). They are essentially javascript files that are installed like an extension. At the top you define the domains for your script to run on and you have access to modify the DOM. There are lots of examples at http://userscripts.org/ . Load a few in chrome and then take a look at the user.js file source to see how they work.

You could also do it via a [Bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), however they are more of a hack compared to Greasemonkey scripts

Answer (score 1):

It's called the [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) in Chrome extension.